# Is there a means of using indefinite articles with plural nouns?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

I encountered the following sentence:

> In programming, types are a means of classifying values.

According to Google, ["are a means of"](https://google.com/search?q="are+a+means+of") and ["is a means of"](https://google.com/search?q="is+a+means+of") are used a lot.

According to "A Concise Dictionary of Correct English",

> the plural of the noun *mean*, may be treated as a singular, as in *a means to an end*.

I wonder, in which cases it is appropriate to use indefinite articles with plural nouns. Is it reserved only for special cases or it can be used whenever someone feels that something is singular?

Fox example, subtitles distributed in a file look like a singular thing. So, at some point of my life, I wrote something like

> The torrent has only an English subtitles, but I want a French ones too.

I still have a feeling that I did something wrong, but I don't know how to word it better.

Comment: This happens with plurale tantum sometimes; I've heard "a scissors" before, though personally I would never say that.

Comment: @DanBron and people say *a scissor* (Google it), so the word does not actually  occur only in the plural.

Comment: Yes, we use a/an with singular count nouns, so in *a means to an end*,  means is indeed being  "treated as a singular"  noun. **Some** can often be used as a plural indefinite determinate. So your last sentence can  be 'The torrent has only English subtitles, but I want (some)  French ones too.' Note: *some* is optional here and doesn't change the meaning much.

Comment: _Some_ is indefinite, but it's not an article; it's a quantifier.

Comment: And to make it clear, *an English subtitles* is incorrect, because the word *subtitles* is not considered (or "being treated as") a singular noun. No native speaker speaking standard English uses it that way. An example with a plural count noun is *Some kites fly higher than others.*

Comment: In 'Examinations are a means of appraisal' and 'The examination is a means of appraisal', 'means' is certainly **plural in form** but that does not define it as a 'plural noun'. 'Police' is etically plural (more than one referent), singular in form (countification to 'polices' for different constabularies does occur), and takes plural agreement. 'News' is etically arguably non-count, arguably plural in form, but takes singular agreement. 'Data' is almost always considered to be plural in form.